# IOS Enterprise Program - Can an Association distribute to members with the Enterprise Program

Tags: ios, mobile, distribution

IOS Enterprise Program - Can an Association distribute to members with the Enterprise Program

We have an Association of Parents Against Texting & Driving and want to distribute anti-texting application only to our members

If the Enterprise Program does not meet this need, what might?

Comment: Any particular reason you cannot just put it on the regular app store (assuming that Apple won't reject it)? Is there harm if non-members stumble upon it? If you don't want non-members to use it, you can require a password login. Many apps do that. You just have to give the reviewer at Apple one, too.